# How to choose overload method suggestion order in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, overloading

Say a class has a some methods with same name and different parameters. How do I tell VS to suggest them in a particular order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done. Simples.  Overloads are ordered ascending by the number of parameters. Suspect you would indeed need to write a plug in.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep to the convention of having all common parameters appear in the same order in every overload. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Do be consistent in the ordering of parameters in overloaded members.
>   Parameters with the same name should appear in the same position in
>   all overloads.

I don't think there's a way of ordering Intellisense without creating a plugin that interacts with it.