# Visual studio intellisense. Order overloads of methods

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a function with an overload. The overload was added for compatibility with older code. Annoyingly when typing a call to the method call the overload version compatibility version is displayed first in intellisense.

Is there anyway to specify the default or order in which overloads are displayed by intellisense? An attribute or something?

The other solution would be to rename the methods and not use overloads.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`Obsolete` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?  Might make sense to use it in your case to discourage use of the overload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change the order of constructors listed in IntelliSense in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391332/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-order-of-constructors-listed-in-intellisense-in-vis)

Comment: Apart from making your own VS Intelisense provider, no

Comment: I like the use of the obsolete attribute

Comment: @apc, do you means the obsolete solved your issue? If so, I will recommend James Thorpe to add a reply with his comment :)

Comment: I'm afraid Obsolete dosn't work, the Deprecated method still appears first in the intelisense

Comment: @apc, we cannot order the overload methods, please check this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232324/how-to-choose-overload-method-suggestion-order-in-vs

Comment: I think the hope was marking it obsolte would push it to the bottom of the list.